# Any way to track a player on the map?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Is there any way to track another player on the map?

If you're trying to meet up with someone, or find somebody that crossed you, it can be hard to keep track of which of the 16 white dots on the map is the person you're looking for.

Comment: There is a "highlight player" option on the phone, but I've not figured it out yet.  Just select the player from your contact list - the option is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I had a play with the highlight player option and it's just a bit lame. Select the player from your phone's contact list and select "highlight". This makes the player's blip on the map flash. It doesn't really help with the mini radar, due to the amount of icons on it, but it does work.

Comment: No problem - glad to help, not that it *is* much help!